# How to find the currently displayed fragment on android using Xamarin

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm trying to work out a way to get the currently displayed fragment on a Android app I'm working on. I have a Startup View that loads fragments, what I need to do is display a popup message when the user taps the back button but only when the using is tapping the back button from a certain fragement. For example:

Fragment A > Nav to.. > Fragment B > Nav to... > Fragment C

If the user clicks the back button from fragment C then nothing is displayed and the user goes back to fragment B as expected. But when the user click back on fragment B a popup is displayed asking the user to confirm that action before being allowed to continue back to fragment A, I hope that makes sense.

I know about the OnBackPressed() which I can override on a view but I cant touch that in a fragment. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Hi when you add a new transaction replace use a key TAG

```
var ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
ft.Replace(Resource.Id.details, details, "FRAGMENT1");
```

and if you need to check if the specify fragment is visible

```
Fragment myFragment = (Fragment)FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("FRAGMENT1");
if (myFragment.IsVisible){
//your code here
}
```

or if you need to get and check all of fragments inside the fragment manager you can use this

```
var fragmentsarray = FragmentManager.Fragments;
foreach(var fragment in fragmentsarray)
{
    if (fragment.IsVisible) {
        //put the code to use and get the tag to identify the current Fragment
        string tag = fragment.Tag;
    }
}
```

if need more specify Fragments info you can check the Android Docs here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Hope it helps you